# blender particle cache impediments to farm rendering

Tags: rendering

I have been working with SheepIt farm rendering for a while and see others commenting on some impediments that an enhancement to blender could help solve.  I'm not sure of a better place to post this as I don't know if there is a product management team to submit enhancement requests.

If one creates long particle or cloth or fluid simulations, there are folder collections of many small cache files, one per frame.

A farm often has a file size limit, in this use case the blender file plus the simulation cache folders enclosed in a zip file that could easily exceed this limit.  And a farm often sends one or a small subset of frames to each helper (client) host.   So a rendering project goes through "gyrations" of dividing up the farm rendering project into subsets of frame groups to overcome this restriction.   Not a simple task, although scripting does help.   But this effort detracts from farm rending just when a farm is ideal (large rendering tasks).

It could be useful if I were able to include a read-only, read-back cache reference to these that used URLs (ftp: or http:, etc).   If the primary (read/write) cache exists (my local project machine), that would be used during render.  If the primary (read/write) cache does not exist, but the URL reference was valid (i.e., I uploaded the cache to a publicly accessible server), that cache would be used.   Call this the "alternative cache".   So when I submit such a vast job to a farm, all rendering hosts would end up accessing the alternative cache on my publicly accessible server (perhaps even on my Dropbox/Public folder), for the few small cache files they need for the frame they were assigned to render.